# Using "for x not in y"

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to make a dynamic function that executes the Fibonacci sequence. It starts with a hashtable that assigns values to positions and then returns it. But if the position isn't in the hashtable, the code stores the value in the hashtable along with that position. Here's the code:

```
 def dyn_fib(n):
     memo = {1:0, 2:1}
     if n <= 2:
         return memo[n]
     else:
         for n not in memo:
             memo[n] = memo[n-2] + memo[n-1]
     return memo[n]
```

All I have to do is edit the 'else' statement to store new values in the hashtable using

```
memo[n] = memo[n-2] + memo[n-1]
```

for any position "n" in not yet listed in memo, and then loop that until you get to "n". I thought I could use

```
 for n not in memo:
```

but Geany is saying there is a syntax error. I think it's because if n = 5, it needs to compute 3 and 4 before 5 but I'm not sure how to put "for any position n not yet in memo" into a python statement. Anyone know how to do this? (I feel like it's simple but I'm not well versed in Python by any stretch.)

Comment: There is no `for <target> not in <iterable>` syntax. `in` is not a *containment operator* here, using `not` makes no sense here. There are an infinite number of integers not in `memo`, Python cannot possibly iterate over all those. That's ignoring other key types (dictionaries can contain any number of types of keys).

Comment: Well, unless you define a superset, "not in memo" is an infinite amount of numbers, so that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It's also worth noting that your code is completely broken - because `memo` is *inside* the function, it gets rebuilt every time you call it. Again, this is why decorators are used, it keeps the memos outside the function.

Comment: I am learning so much right now, thanks all!

Comment: You might want to learn about [memoization](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php), which is the proper way of doing that. As @jonrsharpe has mentioned, there is a better way.

Answer (score 13):

You can't generally say `for x not in y` because there are an infinite number of objects that *aren't* in y.

For your specific case, I think something like this might work:

```
[x for x in range(0, n) if x not in y]
```